# Where does Model Derivative API store the translated .SVF files when using 3rd party cloud storage or local storage

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I am currently trying Autodesk Forge to integrate it to my Application, and need to clarify regarding the storage location of files. I am aware that we can use a 3rd party cloud storage (DropBox, Google Drive) or local storage to store the model files (.ifc, .rvt etc.) However, I need to understand where the .svf files are stored after being translated when using such a 3rd party storage. Are they stored where the model files are originally stored (cloud or local storage) or are they stored in the storage space provided by AutoDesk with its account? As I know, if we upload the model file to the AutoDesk BIM360 Data Storage, the translated file will also be stored on the same location. So how does it work when we are using a 3rd party storage?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translated emits (derivatives) are stored in the Forge OSS and you can query the [manifest endpoint](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET/) to enumerate them for the path to download them. For example:

```
"derivatives": [
    {
      "name": "A5.iam",
      "hasThumbnail": "true",
      "status": "success",
      "progress": "99% complete",
      "outputType": "svf",
      "children": [
        {
          "guid": "d998268f-eeb4-da87-0db4-c5dbbc4926d0",
          "type": "geometry",
          "role": "3d",
          "name": "Scene",
          "status": "success",
          "progress": "99% complete",
          "hasThumbnail": "true",
          "children": [
            {
              "guid": "4f981e94-8241-4eaf-b08b-cd337c6b8b1f",
              "type": "resource",
              "progress": "99% complete",
              "role": "graphics",
              "mime": "application/autodesk-svf"
            },
            {
              "guid": "d718eb7e-fa8a-42f9-8b32-e323c0fbea0c",
              "type": "resource",
              "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bW9kZWxkZXJpdmF0aXZlL0E1LnppcA/output/1/A5.svf.png01_thumb_400x400.png",
              "resolution": [
                400.0,
                400.0
              ],
              "mime": "image/png",
              "role": "thumbnail"
            },
            {
              "guid": "34dc340b-835f-47f7-9da5-b8219aefe741",
              "type": "resource",
              "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bW9kZWxkZXJpdmF0aXZlL0E1LnppcA/output/1/A5.svf.png01_thumb_200x200.png",
              "resolution": [
                200.0,
                200.0
              ],
              "mime": "image/png",
              "role": "thumbnail"
            },
            {
              "guid": "299c6ba6-650e-423e-bbd6-3aaff44ee104",
              "type": "resource",
              "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bW9kZWxkZXJpdmF0aXZlL0E1LnppcA/output/1/A5.svf.png01_thumb_100x100.png",
              "resolution": [
                100.0,
                100.0
              ],
              "mime": "image/png",
              "role": "thumbnail"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Can refer to sample code [here](https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io/blob/master/server/results.js) to retrieve the derivatives and you can go from there to persist them to your own storage.

Comment: Hi @BryanHuang , thank you for the reply! yes I saw that code sample which I can use to download the derivatives. So if I download the derivatives using the above sample code, and store them locally, and delete the derivatives from the Forge OSS using DELETE end-point, would I be able to just use the downloaded file for the viewing purpose? Is this a recommended approach? Because I saw in that code sample that downloading derivatives is something that is not "officially" supported by Autodesk and may break in the future?

Comment: yes so long as you download all the derivatives and persevere their original relative paths then you can point to them as svfUrl in your load options in Viewer and safely rid off their OSS copies - see live sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dukedhx/73a95kLf/). Taking the derivatives offline is officially supported while localizing or modifying the Viewer library  is never supported and against the usage license.